# Write the expression(I don't know understand the question)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Write the expression (p^ ~q) ^ r, using only the operators v and ~.

The question meant the ^ operator with v operator?

Comment: hm so if i get this right, ^ means AND, v means OR and ~ means negation. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: is it replace the operator ^ with v operator?

Comment: the question is asking you to rewrite the logical expression (p AND (NOT q)) AND r using only the operations OR and NOT

Answer (score 3):

No, we can not just replace the $\wedge$ with a $\vee$. This would be wrong because they are not the same thing.

We have:
$$(p \wedge \sim q) \wedge r$$
We need to convert this to OR and NOT somehow. Conversions between AND and OR are done with De Morgan's Law:
$$\sim (u \wedge v) \iff \sim u \vee \sim v$$
Using this, we can take the negation of both sides to find that:
$$u \wedge v \iff \sim (\sim u \vee \sim v)$$
Now, where ever you see a $\wedge$, you can use this formula by substituting the appropriate $u$ and $v$ to convert the expression into something with only $\sim$ and $\vee$. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $(p \wedge \neg q) \wedge r = \neg (\neg((p \wedge \neg q) \wedge r))$. It's all De Morgan's laws from there.

P.S. Since I'm going to guess you don't know De Morgan's laws, there is a master mathematician who know's just about everything. His name is Google.